# How do I pin a trash bin to the GNOME Shell Activities overview?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, trash

How do I pin a trash bin to the GNOME Shell Activities overview?

Comment: This extension adds it to the panel. Maybe a good option: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/48/trash/

Comment: @Kendor can you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 3):

This extension adds it to the panel. Maybe a good option: [extensions.gnome.org/extension/48/trash](http://extensions.gnome.org/extension/48/trash)